# PHP/JavaScript MP3 player to sample and sell songs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, paypal

I used jPlayer to make a custom MP3 player for a buddy of mine's site, but now he want to be able to hide the links (you can see them in JavaScript) and make the songs available for download only through Paypal purchase.  In other words, he wants to keep the player on his site as is, but to make any download of his songs purchase only.  I'm at a complete loss on where to start in such a venture.  Can anyone gimmie some direction?

Just to clarify, I know I cant "hide the script", but I was hoping someone might know a way to get jPlayer to read from a server (php return) or an alternative player thats just as easy to style.  I think I can set the paypal links up pretty easy, but not sure waht to do to keep m3's from being found in javascript without racking my brain (not getting paid) to find a server-side solution.

I'm not being paid, so I'm trying to find a quick, easy, free solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really aren't going to be able to truly *hide* anything in JavaScript, certainly not from anyone who knows to turn on the Network tab of Firebug or IE9's developer tools. You're probably going to need some help from your server to make downloading from the preview player less feasible.

The simplest option is **not** to provide the to-be-purchased tracks through the web player at all. Many sites successfully offer only 30-sec samples or do something like add a periodic tone to the track. The download mp3 files can only be accessed with a validation code from the purchase. A PHP script would confirm the code, read the MP3 from a folder outside the web root and pass it along to the browser (with the correct Content-type and file disposition headers).

If it's absolutely mission-critical to provide the unaltered audio without allowing it to be downloaded, jPlayer does seem to have some support for streaming mp3... google a bit for streaming mp3 server and see if anything available there is available to you on your server.

Either way, you'll keep the to-be-purchased MP3s out of the wwwroot/htdocs folder and serve them up when the purchase is confirmed.

Edit:

There are free/open-source streaming mp3 servers, but I don't know whether your host is flexible enough to let you install one. The advantage of streaming the mp3 to jPlayer is that jPlayer isn't actually downloading the mp3... you reserve that for the paying fans! Google offered up these links you might find useful (haven't tried myself):

http://www.icecast.org/

http://www.vibestreamer.com/

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAudioStreaming.html